# Get class object from string

Tags: python, django, string, class, getattr

I'm writing the following to generate URLs for my urls.py:

```
urls = {
    'overview': {
        r'^$':          [ 'Index' ],
        r'^/account$':  [ 'Account' ],
    },

    'content': {
        r'^/content$':        [ 'Index' ]
        r'^/content/upload$': [ 'Uploader', 'Default' ]
    }

}

urlpatterns = patterns('')

for module, spec in urls.iteritems():
    urlpatterns += patterns('views.'+ module,
        [
                url(regex, (getattr(module.capitalize() , 'as_view'))(), action=view[0])
            if len(view) == 1 else
                url(regex, (getattr(view[0], 'as_view'))(), action=view[1])
            for regex, view in spec.iteritems()
        ]
    )
```

I have modules `overview` and `content`, with classes `Overview`, and `Content` and `Uploader`, respectively.

If the `view` array (e.g., `[ 'Index' ]` contains a single element, I use the capitalized form of the module (e.g., `overview` becomes `Overview`) to generate the route:

```
url(r'^$', Overview.as_view(), action='Index')
```

whereas if it contains two elements, (e.g., `[ 'Uploader', 'Default' ]`), the first element specifies the class name and the second the method:

```
url(r'^$', Uploader.as_view(), action='Default')
```

As you may have noticed, the issue is with my use of `getattr()`, whose first argument requires a class reference. So, my question is *whether there is any way to get the class object from a string that contains the identifier of said class object*, e.g., the `Uploader` class from `'Uploader'`.

As a disclaimer these are not my exact routes, just an example. And of course further comments are welcome with respect to my overall design here as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd say there are two common ways of doing it. Consider example below:

```
from random import choice


class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = 'in A'


class B(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = 'in B'


class C(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = 'in C'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    classes = ['A', 'B', 'C']
    class_name = choice(classes)
    print class_name

    # 1st way
    obj = globals()[class_name]()
    print obj.name

    # 2nd way
    import sys
    obj = getattr(sys.modules['__main__'], class_name)()
    print obj.name

    # 3rd way - not recommended
    obj = eval(class_name)()
    print obj.name
```

Comment: Ah, interesting. So, with respect to the second way, is it that `getattr` can operate on more than just classes/objects (namely, the `__main__` module's "symbol table"), or is it that modules and classes are actually of the same nature? (Being that they both have 'attributes'). Thanks by the way!

Comment: Remember that everything in Python is an object, even the module ;)

Comment: Oh right, cool. So how have Python's language designers avoided a hefty performance penalty with such a thoroughly object-oriented approach? I suppose I can just look these things up at this point though..